# z-Index overlay in google maps version 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to get an overlay in google maps api v3 to appear above all markers. But it seems that the google api always put my overlay with lowest z-index priority. Only solution i've found is to iterate up through the DOM tree and manually set z-index to a higher value. Poor solution.

I'm adding my a new div to my overlay with:

```
 onclick : function (e) {
     var index = $(e.target).index(),
         lngLatXYposition = $.view.overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.getPosition());
         icon = this.getIcon(),
         x = lngLatXYposition.x - icon.anchor.x,
         y = lngLatXYposition.y - icon.anchor.y

     $('<div>test</div>').css({ left: x, position: 'absolute', top: y + 'px', zIndex: 1000 }).appendTo('.overlay');
}
```

I've tried every property I could think of while creating my overlay. zIndex, zPriority etc.

I'm adding my overlay with:

```
$.view.overlay = new GmapOverlay( { map: view.map.gmap });
```

And GmapOverlay inherits from  new google.maps.OverlayView.

Any ideas?

..fredrik

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't change the zIndex of an OverlayView (it has no such property), but it holds panes that contains DOM nodes. That's where you can use the z-index property;

```
...
lngLatXYposition = $.view.overlay.getPanes().overlayLayer.style['zIndex'] = 1001;
...
```

Comment: This is precise answer to the question. I don't see why it is not accepted.

Comment: This just really a hack. See the other top ranked answer for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 46):

If anyone was having the same problem as I was, here is my problem and solution:

I needed an OverlayView which would add tooltips to markers, but my popup overlay kept showing *behind* the markers.

I implemented a subclass of the OverlayView as per the Google documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

When you write your custom `OverlayView.prototype.onAdd` function, you need to specify to which Pane to attach your overlay. I just copied the code without actually reading the surrounding explanation.

In their code, they attach the overlay to the `overlayLayer` pane:

```
var panes = this.getPanes();
panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
```

But there are many different MapPanes you can use:

> "The set of panes, of type MapPanes, specify the stacking order for different layers on
>    the map. The following panes are possible, and enumerated in the order in which they are stacked from bottom to top:"

- MapPanes.mapPane (Level 0)
- MapPanes.overlayLayer (Level 1)
- MapPanes.markerLayer (Level 2)
- MapPanes.overlayMouseTarget (Level 3)
- MapPanes.floatPane (Level 4)

I wanted the overlay to hover over all other info on the map, so I used the `floatPane` pane and problem solved.

So, instead of :

```
this.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(div)
```

you use this :

```
this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: I edited the answer with a sample snipped. This should actually be the correct answer, not the one with z-index hacking.

Comment: Thanks for this, would have never known about floatPane.  This is the right way to do this.

Comment: This is no longer a valid list of the layers used in the map. Updated documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayView

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Brilliant. Fixed my issue.

Comment: Perfect ! That's the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to play around with the paneType of the mapLabel class, I added a paneType property to the MapLabel class from google utility library (https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/maplabel/src/maplabel.js?r=303).

This is usefull to make the label not to be hidden by a polyline.

Please find the code additions to the mapLabel.js file.

```
MapLabel.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var canvas = this.canvas_ = document.createElement('canvas');
  var style = canvas.style;
  style.position = 'absolute';

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';

  this.drawCanvas_();

  var panes = this.getPanes();
  if (panes) {
    // OLD: panes.mapPane.appendChild(canvas)
    var paneType = this.get('paneType');
    panes[paneType].appendChild(canvas);
  }
};

MapLabel = function (opt_options) {
  this.set('fontFamily', 'sans-serif');
  this.set('fontSize', 12);
  this.set('fontColor', '#000000');
  this.set('strokeWeight', 4);
  this.set('strokeColor', '#ffffff');
  this.set('align', 'center');

  this.set('zIndex', 1e3);
  this.set('paneType', 'floatPane');

  this.setValues(opt_options);
}
```

Sample code using the paneType:

```
    var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
      text: segDoc.curr_value.toFixed(0),
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lblLat, lblLng),
      map: map.instance,
      fontSize: 12,
      align: 'center',
      zIndex: 10000,
      paneType: 'floatPane',
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting z-index to 104 for the overLay layer seems to be the "magic" number" if you care about interacting with the markers (i.e. dragging markers).  Any higher than 104 and you can not interact with the markers.  Wondering if there is a less brittle solution...

Answer (score 0):

**Use  panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild**

If you want to allow your layer to be targetable through mouse clicks (and use events such as "click" or CSS pseudo ::hover) then you should add your overlay to the map using  `overlayMouseTarget`

> var panes = this.getPanes();
>
> panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.div_);

Also see:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapPanes

Comment: My initial problem with this was when I was using panes.overlayLayer.appendChild... switching to overlayMouseTarget resolved it.

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer: this is a dodgy solution that may stop working at any time and you definitely shouldn't use this in production.**

For those looking for a quick and dirty solution, this CSS worked for me:

```
.gm-style > div:first-child > div:first-child > div:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 99 !important;
}
```

Use at your own risk!