# Marker on top of OverlayView , GoogleMaps API V3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How can I render a custom OverlayView item behind a marker. When a marker and the overlayView item intersects, always overlayview item is drawn on top. Is there a way to adjust their z depth accordingly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/aeShp5XUtLY).

In the `onAdd` method replace:

```
panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
```

with:

```
panes.mapPane.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Please clarify where you get `panes` from, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The `overlayLayer` pane is also rendered below the markers:

```
var panes = this.getPanes();
panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to adjust the z-order of the contents of the OverlayView, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682626/z-index-overlay-in-google-maps-version-3). Make the DOM nodes in the OverlayView have lower z-order values than the marker.

Comment: I do this for the markers z-index:
mapMarker.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);

and make sure the OverlayView has a z-index of 0. Still doesnt work..