# Show custom MapType over top of polygon overlays

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've been working with Gheat to create customized heat maps as an ImageMapType.  I also have a number of color-coded polygons I would like to show beneath the highlights created by the heatmap.

However, the custom ImageMapType always renders below the polygons, and is obscured by them.  How can I fix this?

Example code below:

```
 var heatmap = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    ...
    });

    var mapOptions = {...};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

var neighborhood1 = new google.maps.Polygon({...});
neighborhood1.setMap(map);
... lots of polys ...

    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(map.overlayMapTypes.length -1, heatmap);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a high z-index on the Polygons? Also, if you can handle generating the heat map client-side, consider using the [new Heatmap Layer in the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps).

Comment: I tried setting the zIndex on the polygons to 0 (I want them behind the heatmap), and that didn't help.  re: Google Heatmap layer -- there are 1000s of points, and if I used Google's API I'd need to figure out how to do the density calculations server-side, which GHeat does for me.

Comment: Ah sorry, I read the question the wrong way. What about a negative zindex on the polygons? I don't think it will work though, because you're using a MapType, which renders below other overlays (polygons, markers, etc) by default. You can order ImageMapTypes though, so another option is to generate tiles of the polygons server side and render the tiles as an ImageMapType under the heatmap layer.

Comment: See my answer, last comment might be moot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2 (2016 Sept 22):

This hack is getting harder to manage, but for now, here's the updated code:

```
el.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.style.zIndex = 102
```

#### Update:

The code for the original answer stopped working. This new code works for me:

```
el.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.style.zIndex = 102
```

`102` was the smallest zIndex that got it to work. You can make it a lot higher to be safe.

#### Orignal answer:

I didn't want it to have to come to this. Here is my solution.

```
el.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes[3].style.zIndex = 300
```

Where `el` is the `<div>` that the map is in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to solve this client-side: [z-Index overlay in google maps version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682626/z-index-overlay-in-google-maps-version-3)

Comment: The heatmap is an ImageMapType, not a OverlayView.  There seems to be no way to manipulate the zIndex of the ImageMapType.  Are you saying that the heatmap should instead be constructed as an OverlayView?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, this fix is for an OverlayView... not sure if ImageMapType can be manipulated in the same way.