# How to put Google Map labels on top?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I am working with polylines in google map. Basically i am trying to draw a line on several roads using polyline.

Now those polylines are blocking(on top) road labels. I have changed the opacity level for better viewing but i really want Google map labels on top.

I have studied styling maps, but i havent found any suitable solutions. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

[image: This is how it looks like now]

[image: This is what i want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tiles(which contain the ground, label, streets etc. ) are delivered as single images, not as layers, so there is no way to put anything between particular features that are shown in the tiles.

But there may be approaches.

Let's assume you have 2 (synchronized) maps, 1 complete map and 1 map where you only display the labels.

When you place the map with the labels on top of the other map it would be able to get the desired effect(which does not mean that I would suggest to it it, I just like  to avoid to say "impossible")

`Demo:` [**http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tq5zmre3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tq5zmre3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// Setup the default map
latlng = [-6.2087634, 106.84559899999999];
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.062521089244896, -68.78645340625002);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  styles: [{
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }],

  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
  mapTypeControl: false,
  backgroundColor: 'hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0)',
  zoom: 5,
  styles: [{
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "on"
    }]
  }],
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
map.bindTo('center', map2, 'center');
map.bindTo('zoom', map2, 'zoom');



new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(15.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
  ],
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  map: map
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="map2" class="map" style="top:-100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Would the main drawbacks to this approach be 1) doubling requests (two maps) and 2) synchronizing map behaviors/events (zoom, click, scroll, etc)? Any others?

Answer (score 4):

There's a cleaner way to achieve this using a single map and a StyledMapType.

```
// Create an overlay to display map labels only
var labelsMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([{
    // Hide all map features by default
    stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
    }]
}, {
    // then turn the label feature on
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
        visibility: 'on'
    }]
}], {
    name: 'Labels'
});

// Add to the map's overlay collection
map.overlayMapTypes.push(labelsMapType);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam, it looks very promising however it didn't work for me

Comment: This does work. You also need to adjust the z-index of the resultant layer -- e.g. `map.getDiv().firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.style.zIndex = 150` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461885/284164