# PNG as KML layer on google maps overlapping everything

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using KMZ file, that has png file as layer, plus kml file itself with coordinates. However i'm having issue with PNG overlapping an actual map (city names, country names, etc), everything is behind KML layer.

Code:

```
let kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://***.com/2g.kmz?dummy=' + (new Date()).getTime(), {suppressInfoWindows: true, preserveViewport: false})
this.kml.setMap(this.map)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webcoderkz/x7jgr9n4/6/

Comment: Is the problem with the opacity of the PNG?  Or do you really want the map labels to be displayed over the image?

Comment: Related question: [How to put Google Map labels on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217771/how-to-put-google-map-labels-on-top)

Comment: Its with the opacity of png, but same KMZ has opacity: https://beeline.kg/ru/map navigate to Kazakhstan and select Coverage > 2g, i've used the same KMZ, but in my case it has no transparency.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this:

```
img[src*="kmz"] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```