# How to draw a shape in Google Maps, that is below a road layer?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When we draw a shape on Google Maps, using JavaScript API Polygons, it's placed on top of the standard map's layers, including roads. For example, https://jsfiddle.net/andriika/rdf5sx3L/ draws a line using `Polyline` class like following:

[image]

How do we draw a line, that appears below roads layer? Like this:

[image]

Comment: The roads are part of the map tiles.  The only way to do something like that is with two maps, one with everything transparent but the roads, the other without the roads, stack them on top of each other, put the shape on the lower map (if you need interaction, you need to synchronize the maps)

Comment: Related question: [How to put Google Map labels on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217771/how-to-put-google-map-labels-on-top)

Comment: yeah, not a straight forward, but thanks for the suggestion @geocodezip. Do you know if there an easier way to achieve this using any other maps providers (preferably free)