# Setting arbitrary z-index ordering of custom overlays and polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've implemented a custom overlay very similar to the USGSOverlay example provided by Google (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple).  To this I've added the capability of setting the z-index of the divs used to show arbitrary images.  Works fine - I have full control over the relative depth ordering of my custom overlays.

I also have various polygons that I want to display on my map.  Naturally, I can control the relative depth ordering of these elements by setting their z-index via Polygon.setOptions().  That works fine too.

By design, the custom overlays and the polygons are both on the OverlayLayer.  I would like to have arbitrary control over the relative depth ordering of my polygons (P1, P2, ...) and my custom overlays (O1, O2, ...), including interleaving of disparate types.  For example, I might want an ordering of P1, O1, O2, P2, O3, P3.  However, overlays with z-index less than 30 always appear behind all polygons (regardless of the polygon z-index) and overlays with z-index of 30 or greater appear in front of all polygons (regardless of the polygon z-index).

Is all hope lost?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes). The panes, of type MapPanes, specify the stacking order for different layers on the map.

The following panes are available, and are enumerated in the order in which they are stacked from bottom to top:

- `mapPane` is the lowest pane and is above the tiles. It may not receive DOM events. (Pane 0).
- `overlayLayer` contains polylines, polygons, ground overlays and tile layer overlays. It may not receive DOM events. (Pane 1).
- `overlayShadow` contains the marker shadows. It may not receive DOM events. (Pane 2).
  overlayImage contains the marker foreground images. (Pane 3).
- `floatShadow` contains the info window shadow. It is above the overlayImage, so that markers can be in the shadow of the info window. (Pane 4).
- `overlayMouseTarget` contains elements that receive DOM mouse events, such as the transparent targets for markers. It is above the floatShadow, so that markers in the shadow of the info window can be clickable. (Pane 5).
- `floatPane` contains the info window. It is above all map overlays. (Pane 6).

This object contains the DOM elements in which overlays are rendered. They are listed below with 'Pane 0' at the bottom and 'Pane 6' at the top.

Also try to check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682626/z-index-overlay-in-google-maps-version-3) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks KENdi.  I've actually been using MapPanes for my custom overlays as a fallback approach since this at least ensures a consistent depth ordering between custom overlays and polygons (overlays always behind polygons).  And I understand that I could choose a different layer if I wanted overlays to always appear in front.  However, unless I'm missing something fundamental, it seems like I would have to have my overlays on the overlayLayer for there to be any chance of interleaving overlays and polygons (for example, one polygon in front of an overlay and another one behind it).