# How can I force Google Map Marker to render on top of overlay views?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I have a google map (rendered using React-Google-Maps) that has several overlay view components, and a map marker component. I'd like the map marker to always be on top of the overlay views.

What I have looks something like this:

[image]

I've tried a few solutions, but so far nothing has worked:

- I tried setting z-indexes in every way imaginable, and it does not appear to make a difference.
- I've set the map marker options to include `{optimized: false}`, but that also does not affect rendering.
- I can't move the overlay views to a different pane because I need them to be clickable, and the `OVERLAY_MOUSE_TARGET` is the only pane where that is possible.
- I even tried to render the elements in a different order using `setTimeout()`, but that also did not fix the issue.

Is there any way to force the marker to render on top of the OverlayViews?

Comment: Do you set zIndex using maps api instruction?

Comment: Hi Ali, yes I did. I tried both options, directly on the component, and trying both the regular and defaultZIndex

Comment: Check this answer about mapPanes https://stackoverflow.com/a/17270714/4700922